# Can I multiplex using modern C++ (STL/Boost)?

Tags: c++, networking, boost

I am writing an application that receives packets from 2+ UDP ports. I could have my application recv (boost) on two separate threads (STL). I understand the mechanics from a theoretical point of view of multiplexing this process. I could resort to select and poll from the UNIX standard, but I would like to see if there are any modern C++ tools in boost or STL for me to solve this?

Comment: You might want to look at [`boost::asio`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Comment: I'd wager you don't want to use [STL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library)